# File/FileInputStream relative path strange behaviour

Tags: java, file

I set java property user.dir to */home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir*. Also I have file *q.txt* inside above folder.

Below is the code snippets and their return values (after =):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") = /home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir
new File(".").getAbsolutePath() = /home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir/.
new File(".").exists() = true
new File("q.txt").getAbsolutePath() = /home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir/q.txt
new File("q.txt").exists() = false
new File(new File("q.txt").getAbsolutePath()).exists() = true
new FileInputStream("q.txt") = threw FileNotFoundException
```

So that as you can see file is realy exists in file system. When I try to get it with absolute path, everything is well. When I try to get it with relative path, it fails.

What do I wrong with relative path?

**EDITED:**

Small application that demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("user.dir", "/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.out.println(new File("q.txt").exists());
        System.out.println(new File("q.txt").isFile());
        System.out.println(new File("q.txt").canRead());

        System.out.println(new File("q.txt").getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(new File(new File("q.txt").getAbsolutePath()).exists());
        System.out.println(new File(new File("q.txt").getAbsolutePath()).isFile());
        System.out.println(new File(new File("q.txt").getAbsolutePath()).canRead());

        try {
            new FileInputStream("q.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir
false
false
false
/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir/q.txt
true
true
true
java.io.FileNotFoundException: q.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

**EDITED 2:**

I also tried another simple example:

```
File f = new File("q1.txt");
System.out.println(f.createNewFile());
System.out.println(f.getPath());
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

An output:

```
true
q1.txt
/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir/q1.txt
```

In result file is created in directory from which I launch the application. Not in `user.dir` directory. And `getAbsolutePath()` returns incorrect file path.

Comment: Could you provide code that does all the logging and testing so that we could test this ourselves easier?

Comment: Sample code is added.

Comment: Can you print file.getPath() for both cases? Seems that there is a resolve method called inside for the Strings and getPath will print without resolve anything.

Comment: `q.txt` and `/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir/q.txt` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would serve you better to read the [javadoc for File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

A little bit of explanation to help you get started:

For the constructor that you're using:

> **public File(String pathname)**
>
> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string,
>   then the result is the empty abstract pathname.

So essentially what you get is a File instance, with the abstract pathname "`q.txt`".

What happens when you do a `getAbsolutePath()` on this. Again from the javadoc:

> **`public String getAbsolutePath()`**
>
> Returns the absolute pathname string of this abstract pathname.
>    If this abstract pathname is already absolute, then the pathname 
>    string is simply returned as if by the `getPath()` method. If this 
>    abstract pathname is the empty abstract pathname then the pathname 
>    string of the current user directory, which is named by the system 
>    property `user.dir`, is returned. Otherwise this pathname is resolved in 
>    a system-dependent way. On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made 
>    absolute by resolving it against the current user directory.
>
> On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute 
>    by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by 
>    the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current 
>    user directory.

Do you see what is happening? Especially, with respect to `user.dir`?

More hints:

Now create another variable, e.g.

`File newFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "q.txt")`.

Try the same operations on `newFile`. Try using `getParent()` on your previous one as well as on this one. You'll see the difference.

I hope this helps clarify a few points for you :)

Comment: Thank you. It clarify something for me. So that, can we say that using relative path as in my example is incorrect?

Comment: @sasha_trn: you're right. corresponding to the use-case that you're trying to achieve, your usage of relative path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It is because File(String str) will call normalize, but getAbsolutePath will also call resolve, there is where the user.dir is being used. Look at the following example.

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", "/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir");

File fString = new File("Test.txt");
File fAbsolutePath = new File(fString.getAbsolutePath());

System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
System.out.println(fString.getPath());
System.out.println(fAbsolutePath.getPath());
```

Here is the output:

```
/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir
Test.txt
\home\alex\projects\poltava\rpgu\workingdir\Test.txt
```

You can see the src code here:
new File(String str)
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/File.java#File.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%2Cjava.lang.String%29

getAbsolutePath:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/File.java#File.getAbsolutePath%28%29

Comment: On Linux machine I have following output of your example:
`/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir
Test.txt
/home/alex/projects/poltava/rpgu/workingdir/Test.txt`